# how to disable a link and only show it once all fields are filled

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to disable the link or show a warning if the user hasn't filled the below fields. When the fields are filled up the user will be able to click the button again.

```
<form class="form-wrap mt-4">                               
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <div class="select-wapper">
      <%= select_tag :state, options_for_select([["Select a state",""]] + State.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] },selected: current_or_guest_user.search_state ), required: true, id: "state"%>
    </div>
    <div class="select-wapper">
      <%= select_tag :city, options_for_select([["Select a City",""]] + City.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, selected: current_or_guest_user.search_city), required: true, :id => 'city' %>
    </div>
    <a href="/welcome/search" class="btn-form search-btn">Submit<i class="pe-7s-angle-right"></i></a>                                      
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

disable link with attribute onclick="return false"

```
$('#city, #state').change(function() {
    if($("option:selected").length == 2)
        $('.search').attr('onclick', '')
})
```